# Is this a Chrome bug in Xpath evaluation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath

Open this page: http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2

And run this simple xpath search query in the console. Then the browser tab crashes

```
for(var k=0, kl=2000; k < kl; k++){
    console.log(k);
    var xpathResult = document.evaluate("//div[@class='hello']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
}
```

On chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)  on Macbook Pro, OSX 10.10.5

Unfortunately i have to run the xpath on this page a couple of thousands of time to search for different elements. So i can't get away with not doing that many calls to evaluate.

The crash is dependent on the xpath term. for some terms it crashes and for some others it does not.

It fails consistently on the same count so it makes me think it is not a timing issue or garbage collection issue.

I am not getting any error codes so I am not sure where else to look.

[image]

***Update***
After further investigation we believe this is a legitimate Chrome bug or at least not very good way of releasing memory. What happens is that if your xpath starts with / or // then the search context is expanded to all of DOM and for some reason chrome keeps the DOM or some other intermediary object in memory. If the xpath does starts with relative path like (div/p) and the search scope ( second argument) is set to portions of the DOM the memory consumption is much more reasonable and there is no crash. Thanks to @JLRishe for several hints that were very helpful to get to this conclusion.

***Update2***
I filed a bug on chromium. But after a few months they rejected the bug as wont-fix. I managed to work around it for the time being.

Comment: What is the purpose of evaluating the same XPath 2000 times? Could you show us code that demonstrates what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a chrome extension that scrapes pages. Given a recipe to extract all the elements of the page you end up running the xpath many times. this page is pretty extreme case.  you can see the extension here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-scraper/nndknepjnldbdbepjfgmncbggmopgden?hl=en-US&gl=US

Comment: Well, that was just an example. There is an xpath array that holds all the different xpaths for extracting different elements of the page. That array could get long. I tried to simplify the problem into something as basic as possible. Removed variation of xpath elements and just repeated the same xpath. I was expecting this example to just pass. It might take a while to run but it should not crash.

Comment: If you run the same xpath on the same page you'll get the same results. I have zero issues believing you're running into some memory- or implementation-related issue. Also, if you're searching for specific elements, you probably should use more-specific selectors, which would decrease resource requirements, and maybe just not use xpath for this.

Comment: You may want to use the last argument to `document.evaluate` to re-use the result set.

Comment: you mean like this:  xpathResult = document.evaluate("//div[@class='hello']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, xpathResult);   unfortunately that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I run your code on that page and watch Task Manager, I can see Chrome's working set increase to about 3.3 GB before it eventually crashes after about 1300 iterations.

Each XPath query is causing Chrome to allocate memory for the results and any operation involved in obtaining them, but it seems like it is not releasing any of the allocated memory because you are not releasing control of the thread.

I have found that the working set levels out at 1.65 GB and the operation finishes without crashing if I do this:

```
var k = 0;
var intv = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(k);
    var xpathResult = document.evaluate("//div[@class='hello']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    k += 1;
    if (k >= 2000) {
        clearInterval(intv);
    }
}, 0);
```

so something like that might be a possible solution.

This is still using considerable system resources, and this isn't even including any values you might be storing in the course of your operation. I encourage you to seek out a smarter approach that doesn't require running quite so many XPath queries.

Comment: Yeah. I have not see this happening often. My extension has 25K users so I would have heard of this if it happened more often. But just want to see if there is something I can do to make it not happen. in this case I am not sure why chrome is holding on to so much memory. Is it possible to scope the search to segment of the DOM? In the real extension the search are happening with 2nd element of evaluate() set to nodes within the DOM. So normally does partial DOM searches. But if the xpath begins with // then somehow the scope automatically grows to all of DOM, right?

Comment: @DavidDehghan Yes, any XPath beginning with `/` is an absolute XPath and would start at the root of the DOM. If you want to look at all descendants of a particular node, you can use `.//`: e.g. `.//div[@class='hello']"`.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a bug I can track on (I assume) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list? I couldn't find it.